# How to run Freemarker template with servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, freemarker

I'm writing app with Freemarker templates. I achieved knowledge how to configure and run .ftl templates mechanism through Java class, and make the console or file output to print template result on it.

But how to do it on servlet? How does it works? Im trying to run .ftl file on Tomcat like .jsp files. But it only give me an error ("description The requested resource is not available.").

Could someone explain me how to run .ftl files on servlets?

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet</servlet-class>

    <!-- FreemarkerServlet settings: -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>TemplatePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>NoCache</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ContentType</param-name>
        <param-value>text/html; charset=UTF-8</param-value> <!-- Forces UTF-8 output encoding! -->
    </init-param>

    <!-- FreeMarker settings: -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>incompatible_improvements</param-name>
        <param-value>2.3.22</param-value>
        <!-- Recommended to set to a high value. For the details, see the Java 
            API docs of freemarker.template.Configuration#Configuration(Version). -->
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>template_exception_handler</param-name>
        <!-- Use "html_debug" instead during development! -->
        <param-value>rethrow</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>template_update_delay</param-name>
        <!-- ATTENTION, 0 is for development only! Use higher value otherwise. -->
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>default_encoding</param-name>
        <!-- The encoding of the template files. -->
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>locale</param-name>
        <!-- Influences number and date/time formatting, etc. -->
        <param-value>en_US</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>number_format</param-name>
        <param-value>0.##########</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>freemarker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>tomcat</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>tomcat</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here is my Java code that works, and prints output on console:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");

    FreeMarkerConfiguration configurationWrapper = 
            context.getBean("freeMarkerConf", FreeMarkerConfiguration.class);

    Configuration cfg = configurationWrapper.getConfiguration();

    try {
        cfg.setSharedVariable("title", "SharedTitle");
    } catch (TemplateModelException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    //data.put("title", "Hello");
    data.put("name", "Andrew");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Poland");
    list.add("Austria");
    list.add("Germany");
    list.add("Hungary");

    data.put("countries", list);

    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);

    try {
        Template template = cfg.getTemplate("index.ftl");
        template.process(data, out);

        Template template2 = cfg.getTemplate("list.ftl");
        template2.process(data, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look on this example:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/freemarker-servlet-tutorial-example/

Comment: Nice example, but my requests must be handled by Spring MVC controllers. :<

Comment: You can try this example: https://github.com/freemarker/freemarker-tutorials/tree/master/01-hello-world

Answer (score 0):

To use FreeMarker with Java Servlets, follow these simple steps:

1. Add Maven dependency.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
       <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
       <version>${freemarker-version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Configure FreeMarker in `web.xml` file.
   Copy and paste the settings from the FreeMarker [website](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html).
3. Dispatch the processing from the Servlet to the FreeMarker 
   template file.

   ```
   request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/show.ftl").forward(request, response);
   ```
4. Clean & build.

Have a look at my [FreeMarker tutorial](http://zetcode.com/java/freemarker/), which shows how to set up FreeMarker in Java console, Servlet, and Spring Boot applications.